# Syntax for WHERE clause with AND/OR?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I'm working on a simple query that will pull a list of all patients at a clinic who either have a certain diagnosis OR have had a certain procedure done. The diagnosis and procedure codes are separate fields; patients with a diagnosis might not have had a procedure done, and patients who have had a procedure might not have a diagnosis, but I still need all the patients who have had one or the other. Here's the query I've got:

```
SELECT PatientID, PatientName, DateOfBirth
FROM Visit
WHERE VisitStatus = 'Complete'
      AND (DiagnosisCode IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI') OR ProcedureCode IN ('123','456','789'))
```

And yes, both code fields have a varchar data type because certain codes use both letters and numbers.

This is a simplified version of the `WHERE` clause, since I actually have upwards of 60 diagnosis codes and about 30 procedure codes. But I just wanted to make sure my syntax was right. The query is taking absolutely forever to run, but I don't know if that's just because there's a lot of data to sift through or if there's an issue with the syntax that has gotten it stuck in something similar to an infinite loop. I don't have any syntax errors coming up. I originally just had the diagnosis codes, so my `WHERE` clause just looked like `WHERE .... AND DiagnosisCode IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI')`. It still took a while to run, but it did eventually work. But after I added the `OR` part with the procedure codes, it's just running and running and running.

Does this look like it should be running without any problem? Is my syntax correct?

Comment: How many rows has table Visit? I mean, thousands, hundreds of thousands, millons...

Comment: Your syntax is fine. Do you have indexes on the VisitStatus, DiagnosisCode and ProcedureCode columns?

Comment: Query looks ok, but do you have a composite index on ( VisitStatus, DiagnosisCode, ProcedureCode) as a single index that qualifies the where condition.  Definitely from this sample have the VisitStatus in the first position.

Comment: @Adrián - thousands. The record system has only been in place for a couple of years so luckily I'm not dealing with anything more than that. There are about 90,000 visits recorded.

Comment: @KenWhite Adding ProcedureCode after DiagnosisCode doesn't help.

Comment: And in response to the others, nope, no indexes. That's probably my issue.

Comment: @DRapp that index wouldn't satisfy the whole query, because the ProcedureCode column won't help at all match the that part of the IN clause. He needs two indexes, and to split this apart with a UNION to be sure Sql Server can see how to use them.

Comment: @Tay Thanks for your reply. I think it should not take so long based on 90.000 records. You may add indexes as others suggested, and see if performance improves greatly. And to provide a different approach, if you are using almost every diagnosis code and almost every procedure code, you may do the opposite query with NOT IN (instead of using IN) and see what happens.

Comment: @Adrián - I'm not using anywhere close to all the codes, but that's a good idea and I'll definitely keep it in mind in the event that I ever have to use that different approach :)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: I didn't say a thing about adding procedure code after diagnosis code. I asked if there were **indexes on the VisitStatus, DiagnosisCode and ProcedureCode columns**.

Comment: @KenWhite That's even worse. Indexes on the columns independently don't help. You only get to use the one index that fits a table.

Comment: @Joel: I don't think you get one index per query. Even lower-end DBMSs will use multiple indexes where they're needed. If SQL Server can't do this, it would be extremely disappointing.

Comment: You can use more than one index per query, but you only get one index per table reference. Pretty much all relational DBs work like that. You **don't** index columns independently. You **do** design indexes to cover multiple columns that match up with actual queries handled by the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do a little better by taking a UNION of two queries. This can help Sql Server produce a better execution plan that better hits your indexes:

```
SELECT PatientID, PatientName, DateOfBirth
FROM Visit
WHERE VisitStatus = 'Complete'
    AND DiagnosisCode IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI')

UNION

SELECT PatientID, PatientName, DateOfBirth
FROM Visit
WHERE VisitStatus = 'Complete'
    AND ProcedureCode IN ('123','456','789')
```

To gain further improvements, I'd look for these two indexes on the table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX MyVisitIndex1
ON Visit (VisitStatus, ProcedureCode)
INCLUDE (PatientID, PatientName, DateOfBirth);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX MyVisitIndex2
ON Visit (VisitStatus, DiagnosisCode)
INCLUDE (PatientID, PatientName, DateOfBirth);
```

Comment: Ah, the UNION seems to have worked! It still took a while since I never tried the indexes, but this is definitely an improvement.

Comment: Can you quantify the improvement? From x seconds to y seconds? You may also find that, given the indexes, Sql Server was smart enough to produce the same execution plan without the union rewrite.

Comment: We're actually talking minutes (the system as a whole has been really slow today though so that could be part of it - it's in the process of being overhauled). The original query is still running and is currently 11 minutes in, and the union version finished in 4 minutes.